# difficult combinatory poker problem

Tags: combinatorics

how many poker hands are there that don´t have 2 cards of the same number? (the poker deck contains 52 cards: 13 numbers and 4 suits; a hand contains 5 cards); I tried to do this problem with combinations: my answer was: 4${13\choose 5}$,but the answer of my book is: $4^5{13\choose 5}$ so i don´t know how to solve it; please i would appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

There are $\binom{13}5$ sets of $5$ numbers; now you have to account for the suits. Each of the $5$ numbers can appear in any one of the $4$ suits. Suppose that you’ve picked the numbers $2,3,4,5$, and $6$; your $2$ could be any one of $4$ cards: $\spadesuit2$, $\heartsuit2$, $\diamondsuit2$, or $\clubsuit2$. Similarly, your $3$ could be any one of $4$ cards, and the same is true of your $4$, your $5$, and your $6$. Thus, after you’ve chosen the $5$ numbers you can still choose suits for the $5$ cards in $4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4=4^5$ ways, for a total of $4^5\binom{13}5$ possible hands.

Your figure of $4\binom{13}5$ is the number of possible flushes ($5$ cards of the same suit): there are $4$ ways to choose the suit and $\binom{13}5$ ways to choose $5$ cards in that suit.

Comment: @David: You’re welcome!