# poker combinations problem

Tags: combinatorics

how many poker hands are there that contains at least 2 cards of the same number? (A poker hand contains 5 cards) I tried to do it with combinations: my poker hands need to have at least 2 cards of the same number so first I have ${13\choose 2}$ combinations with the first two cards, then for the other three cards I have ${50\choose 3}$ combinations so my answer is :${13\choose 2}{50\choose 3}$ and it gives : 1,528,800 but in my book the answer is: 1,281,072 so can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Use the answer to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574149/difficult-combinatory-poker-problem) and the fact that every poker hand either does or does not contain at least two cards of the same number. How many poker hands are there altogether?

Comment: so the answer should be :${52\choose 5}-4^5{13\choose 5}$ and it gives!! :D but why does not work my method?

Comment: @David: Your $\binom{13}2$ picks two **numbers**, not two cards with the same number; there are $\binom{13}1\binom42$ ways to pick two cards with the same number. But you still can’t simply multiply this by $\binom{50}3$, because that overcounts: any hand that has three or four of the same number will be counted more than once in $\binom{13}1\binom42\binom{50}3$.